# Error loading Iran's map in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iran's map in Mozilla Firefox and other browsers other than Google Chrome does not work. Is there a solution to this problem?

[Link](https://github.com/10bestdesign/jqvmap/blob/master/examples/iran.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this js. It's working in my internet explorer.

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqvmap/1.5.1/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqvmap/1.5.1/maps/jquery.vmap.iran.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some SVG interpreters are stricter than others when parsing SVG paths. I reproduced your error on Firefox 60 for Linux, and found out that the problem are the stray commas your code adds before letter commands in the **d** element of the **path**s.

Your code for Iran's SVG map generates things like

```
<path d="M337.484,105.127c-2.603,0-4.637,6.755-5.276,8.73c-0.574,1.774-
1.697,2.534-2.095,4.611c-0.323,1.688-0.022,3.997-0.181,5.777,c-
0.425,4.993-11.137,1-14.82,1.477c-6.764,0.875-7.284,7.656-12.906,9.999c-
1.299,0.345-2.688,1.319-4.061,0.933,c-1.748-0.492-3.578-1.065-5.457-
```

Substrings like ",c" (two in the snippet above) and ",l" (not shown above but present in the SVG your code generates) make Firefox and Inkscape (an SVG editor) stop drawing the shape at the first occurrence of the problem.

Change your code not to generate commas before letter commands and it should render correctly.